# Access postgres db on host machine from container built with docker compose

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I have a Postgres db set up on a ubuntu box and on the same box I have some containers from a  docker compose which trying to access the database on this box. (The Postgres/database is NOT in a container. it is installed on the box)

I can access the db fine using dbeaver and can even connect to it from the site running on my dev environment on my pc

I'm using a .net core backend to connect to the db.

I have added this to the end of my backend service in the docker compose:

```
extra_hosts:
- "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
```

Also I have tried adjusting the connection string and nothing works

```
Server=host.docker.internal;Port=5432;Database=mydb;User Id=xx;Password=xx;
Server=<IP address>;Port=5432;Database=mydb;User Id=xx;Password=xx;
Server=172.17.0.1;Port=5432;Database=mydb;User Id=xx;Password=xx;
```

Any ideas what to do?

in the logs I can see the following error

```
Connection id "0HMMVM72IIA14", Request id "0HMMVM72IIA14:00000002": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
      System.InvalidOperationException: An exception has been raised that is likely due to a transient failure.
       ---> Npgsql.NpgsqlException (0x80004005): Failed to connect to <IP REMOVED>:5432
       ---> System.TimeoutException: Timeout during connection attempt
         at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.ConnectAsync(NpgsqlTimeout timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.RawOpen(SslMode sslMode, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean isFirstAttempt)
```

Comment: "nothing works" doesn't help. What are the error messages you get?

Comment: @MatBailie getting a InvalidOperationException/ NpgsqlException  with it failing to connect to the database - updated a bit